# Python - Web directory file names return blank (Requests & BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, http, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Using the Requests and BeautifulSoup plugin, I am trying to retrieve all the mp3 file names from a specific web directory and it is returning nothing.

This is the function I am running which contains the problem:

```
archive_url = "http://example.com/audio/"

def get_video_links():

    r = requests.get(archive_url) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html5lib')  
    links = soup.findAll('a') 
    video_links = [archive_url + link['href'] for link in links if link['href'].endswith('mp3')] 
    
    return video_links
```

It is not functioning as it should, so to try to find the problem I ran `print(video_links)` and the command line simply outputs []. It is returning nothing. My only idea is that I could've installed the plugins incorrectly, shouldn't be using Visual Studio 2019, or need to configure the project in a different way. Can anyone spot my stupidity? I seek input humbly.

[(I am attempting to follow this tutorial)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/downloading-files-web-using-python/)

Comment: Maybe because that tutorial mentions `.mp4` files, not `.mp3`s.

Comment: I have tested it on a directory of mp4s just to be sure, not the issue. Thanks however

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would suggest to upload the required modules to run the provided function:

```
import requests 
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Then, redefine the function `get_video_links()` that returns a list when the output `video_links` is a list:

```
def get_video_links(archive_url):

    r = requests.get(archive_url) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html5lib')  
    links = soup.findAll('a') 
    
# ensure to pass a list
    video_links = [archive_url + link['href'] for link in links if link['href'].endswith('mp3')] 
     
    if isinstance(video_links, list):
         return video_links
    else:
        raise AttributeError:
         return("video_links is not a list, convert to list")
    

    return video_links
```

Then, define the input for the function and call it directly from the function, instead of using `print(video_links)` which is an empty list as it is not defined in the code:

```
archive_url = "http://example.com/audio/"
video_links=get_video_links(archive_url=archive_url)
```

In a nutshell:

```
# importing required modules

import requests 
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

# define function to get the video links:
# input: a list built-in
def get_video_links(archive_url):

    r = requests.get(archive_url) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html5lib')  
    links = soup.findAll('a') 
    
# ensure to pass a list
    video_links = [archive_url + link['href'] for link in links if link['href'].endswith('mp3')] 
     
    if isinstance(video_links, list):
         return video_links
    else:
        raise AttributeError:
            print("video_links is not a list, convert to list")
    

    return video_links 

# set input and call it in the function

archive_url = "http://example.com/audio/"
video_links=get_video_links(archive_url=archive_url)
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. I believe the problem lies with the URL I am seeking to download the files from and not the code itself. So at this point I'm clueless but happy to have received help. Thanks.